# How to deploy a web site in python

Tags: python, django, webserver

I am new to python and I am developing a website in django, but would like to know how to publish this web site, I own a semi-dedicated Cloud server with Ubuntu 10.04 LTS, which software should I install to develop a server, I am also optimistically, I hope more than 200 simultaneous accesses it, or have to use a webserver and good ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it multiple ways:

- Running bare django within some kind of process supervisor
- Using reverse proxy to redirect requests to django via particular protocols like FastCGI

### Running django with a process supervisor

One of multiple tools used to make sure a particular service is up is [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/). To install it all you need to do is `sudo apt-get install supervisord`.

After successfull installation you should've been created a `/etc/supervisord/conf.d` directory where you could place all your configuration files for each service you would like to be supervised.

**What does supervisord do?**

Supervisord, among others, checks the current status of service process that was started by a command given in the configuration. Once it has detected the service went down, it attempts to restart it. If it fails too many times within short amount of time, the service is considered errorneous and you'll need to look into the cause of the problem yourself.

**Example configuration file**

```
[program:django-webserver]
directory = /user/foo/my-project
user = foo
command = /user/foo/.virtualenvs/my-project/bin/python /user/foo/my-project/manage.py runserver
stdout_logfile = /user/foo/my-project/logs/supervisord/webserver.out.log
stderr_logfile = /user/foo/my-project/logs/supervisord/webserver.err.log
autostart = true
autorestart = true
environment = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="myproject.settings.production"
```

**Running the machinery**

After pasting configuration above into `/etc/supervisord/conf.d/` directory (e.g. `myproject.conf` file), you can see the current status of service using `sudo supervisorctl` command. You'll get a listing of all configured programs from included configuration files along with their statuses. To reload configuration you should type `reload` in the prompt that has appeared after entering supervisorctl.

After making sure supervisord has loaded your new configuration file, you can type `start django-webserver` then to make supervisor run django and take care of it. Note that `django-webserver` is the name you've passed in the `[program:<name>]` clause in supervisord configuration file.

### Running django using reverse proxy

One of the reverse proxies that are, in my opinion, user-friendly is [nginx](http://nginx.org/). Why should you use a reverse proxy like nginx? It allows you to set up a load balancer, serve files more efficiently and more.

Nginx can be installed by typing `sudo apt-get install nginx`. To make `nginx` talk to your `django-webserver` you need to create configuration file like this one in `/etc/nginx/sites-available` directory.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    access_log /home/foo/myproject/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /home/foo/myproject/nginx/error.log;

    location /statics/ {
        gzip on;
        root /home/foo/myproject/collected_static;
        rewrite ^/statics/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        autoindex off;
        expires 60d;
    }

    location / {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8000;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
        fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
        fastcgi_param CONTENT_TYPE $content_type;
        fastcgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH $content_length;
        fastcgi_param SERVER_PROTOCOL $server_protocol;
        fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT $server_port;
        fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $server_name;

        fastcgi_pass_header Authorization;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
    }
}
```

To make it possible for your django to communicate with nginx, you'll need to install `flup` using `pip install flup` (other alternative is e.g. [gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/)). After you've got flup installed, make sure your django server is running with following command:
`python manage.py runfcgi host=127.0.0.1 port=8000 daemonize=false`

The `daemonize=false` switch is important as it won't create a background daemon.

With django up and running, the only thing left to do is to make the actual nginx site available to the outer world: make a soft link to just-created nginx config inside `/etc/nginx/sites-available` directory inside `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` like so:

```
cd /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject.conf myproject.conf
```

With those steps done, restart nginx using `sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart` and voila.

**It's a good idea to combine both steps to have supervisor take care of django process that will communicate with nginx.**

Comment: :o
I'm impressed! I would like to deeply thank the help!! Unfortunately I could not put into practice yet, but certainly I think that will work!
Thank you!!